# Change angular-material for a $mdDialog

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to remove the gray background when you hover over the 'yes' and 'no' buttons of my `$mdDialog`.  I have managed to change the color of the text by changing it in the `angular-material.css`.  Any ideas?

Here is a pic of the 'NO' and 'YES' buttons I am referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, do not modify original sources of the library. Once you decide to update it to a newer version, all of your changes will be lost. Much better practice is to override original styles with your own. In order to do that, create a separate css file and add it to your site after `angular-material.css`.

To modify background color of buttons in a dialog, you need the following code:

```
md-dialog .md-button:not([disabled]):hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

`.md-button:not([disabled]):hover` is a class responsible for styling hover color of md-button controls. In this case, `!important` is needed to override original color of buttons. Finally, `md-dialog` at the beginning ensures that your styles will be applied only inside dialogs.

**Update 1 - Alternative solution**

Another but more complicated solution is creating a custom confirmation dialog. This way you can completely change appearence of the dialog by using your own template. You can find more about custom dialogs in the Angular Material documentation:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog